# To avoid selecting duplicate Images in app using camera or Gallery option

Tags: android, image

I have a feature of add properties that let user to take image of property using camera or Gallery option what i want to let user avoid taking duplicate images so that whenever user try to select duplicate images user could be restricted to do that.
This is my Code

```
    final String[] items = new String[] { "From Camera", "From Gallery" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Select Image");
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (item == 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                extStorageDirectory = UtilsMethos.CreateAppFolder(AddPropertyActivity.this);
                File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, getString(R.string.app_name)+"_"+ String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+ ".png");
                mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
                try {
                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                dialog.cancel();
            } else {


                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <19){
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_FILE);
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_KITKAT_INTENT_CALLED);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    //      dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.show();
}
And in OnActivityResult() my code is 
if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE) {
                    mImageCaptureUri = intent.getData();
                }else if (requestCode == GALLERY_KITKAT_INTENT_CALLED) {
                    mImageCaptureUri = intent.getData();
                    if(mImageCaptureUri == null){
                        addMultipleImage(intent);
                        return;
                    }
                    final int takeFlags = intent.getFlags()
                            & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                                    | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                    // Check for the freshest data.
                    getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(mImageCaptureUri, takeFlags);
                }
                //          String selectedImagePath = UtilsMethos.getPath(mImageCaptureUri,this);
                String selectedImagePath = UtilsMethos.getPath(this, mImageCaptureUri);
                Bitmap bitmap = UtilsMethos.getBitmapFromPath(selectedImagePath);
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: @Epodax i want user to avoid selecting duplicate images whenever he selects image using camera or gallery option.

Comment: If the user uses the camara he does not select an image but takes a new image. So what would you describe a duplicate while taking pictures?

Comment: @greenapps yes thats exactly what i am asking for

Comment: ??? You did nog answer my question. Please react to the point.

Comment: @greenapps what i need is to implement it while the user select the particular image using gallery rather then picking it using camera.

Comment: Well then start changing the subject of your post. And change the text and the code in your post to be to the point.

Comment: @greenapps if u can help me regarding to the selection from  gallery ,i would appreciate it thanks,would go for camera selection laters .